# Java add variable to string array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a small code that includes citynames which will be displayed.
Now a want a user can add names with a scanner, I know the code for the scanner but not how to add the variable.

Code I have:

```
String[] cityNames = { "Tiel", "Culemborg", "Houten", "Geldermalsen", "Meteren", "Buren" }; 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cityNames));
```

Comment: use a `List<String>` or `Set<String>`

Comment: You can't add variable to array. Its size is fixed once it's created.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot do it with a Array since the size is fixed , once it declared.

You are probably looking for Collections. Prefer to Use   `List` interface  with `ArrayList` implementation.

The reason is that the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is

> Resizable-array implementation of the List interface.

```
List<String> cityNames  = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now you have methods like `add, remove`, ... and many more useful methods on your `cityNames` `List`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `List<String>`, get the input value and add it:

```
List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
cities.add(userInput);
```

List is better to use than array as its length is modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a fixed length. If the amount of Strings in your collection is variable, you´ll have to use a List.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new element to array if index of new element less than the size of array.

```
arr[i]="some value" // to do this i < arr.length
```

If array is completely filled with elements when you assign new value to index previous value will override. You can't add more elements than the size of declared since array has fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Array is fixed size so you can't add the value to it if the size is already filled. For dynamic array use List instead of array.

Do like this

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Tiel", "Culemborg", "Houten", "Geldermalsen", "Meteren", "Buren" ));

list.add("new value1");
list.add("new value2");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use there set, which excludes duplicate entries automatically:

```
Set<String> cities = new HashSet<String>();
cities.addAll(Arrays.asList("Tiel", "Culemborg", "Houten", "Geldermalsen", "Meteren", "Buren"));
```

then to add new city just call:

```
sities.add(newCity);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<String> cityNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Add the city names to cityNames list...

        cityNames.add(input.next());
```